# How to receive action by BroadcastReceiver inside Service

Tags: android, service, action, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent

I have problem with receiving an intent sended by widget as PendingIntent:

```
intent = new Intent(MyService.MY_ACTION);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button, pendingIntent);
```

I added a broadcast receiver to MyService:

```
private BroadcastReceiver mIntentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Intent command received");
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if( MY_ACTION.equals(action))
        {
            doSomeAction();
        }
    }
};
```

and finally I registered this receiver i onCreate method of the service:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(MY_ACTION);
registerReceiver(mIntentReceiver, filter);
```

And now when th MyService is running and I click the button, I get :

```
09-21 14:21:18.723: WARN/ActivityManager(59): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.myapp.MyService.MY_ACTION flg=0x10000000 bnds=[31,280][71,317] }: not found
```

I also tried to add an intent-filter (with MY_ACTION action) to manifest file to MyService but it causes calling onStartCommand method of MyService. And that is not what I want. I need to call the onReceive method of mIntentReceiver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you want to do?

If you register a broadcast receiver in your Service `onCreate` method then:

- You should raise a **broadcast intent**, not a service intent. Change this:

  pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);

To this:

```
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
```

- You service should **be running** to listen for this broadcast event, this will not run your service, since you are registering the receiver when the service is created.

Comment: @aromero, thanks a ton! I was searching SO for about two hours and tried to find the reason for my problem. But your answer finally pointed me to the right place!

Answer (score 1):

For such purposes you should extend your service from `IntentService`. You will receive the broadcast in `onHandleIntent()` method of your service.